# PHP remove the New text after 1 day

Tags: php, html

I would add the New text if one day is not passed but if it is passed i would delete the text New if one day is passed.

I tried this code :

```
  <?php

$farkZaman = time() - strtotime("2017-09-26 19:00:00");

$farkGun = floor($farkZaman / (60 * 60 * 24));

if($farkGun < 1){

    echo "Yeni";

}
?>
```

How can i do ?

I need your help.

Note : I have French but i don't have a good English.

Comment: where u want to add the text? Are you storing the date in database? The text update should be automatic (crons) or on manual reload?

Comment: @Devs i would to add in my home page. The page i have the products. Yes, i have the date in my databases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for.
Here is set $dt as tomorrow with a time (about 24 hours from now GMT+1).

Then I compare if time is less than this time.
If it is I echo the text.

```
$dt = strtotime("2017-09-29 06:40");

If(time()<=$dt){
    Echo "the text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
if(strtotime($date_variable) > strtotime("-1 day")) {
  echo "New";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php

$now = new DateTime();
$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

$created_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2017-09-27 13:00:00")));

$day = $created_date->diff($now)->days; // 0

if($day < 1){
    echo "new texts";
}
?>
```